# node.js app runs from command prompt but not directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a very simple vbscript that is supposed to launch the two nodejs apps needed for my server.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "node C:\!webroot\site.name\server\pubsub.js"
objShell.Run "node C:\!webroot\site.name\server\listen.js"
```

When I execute it, I see two command windows open but one closes immediately.  The `pubsub.js` window stays open and listening like it should but it appears the second execution just disappears.  I can manually execute it without any issue.

Out of curiosity I switched the order and the `pubsub.js` still ran while the other one still closed.

Further troubleshooting reveals that using the start > run command in windows, I get the same behavior:  `pubsub.js` works fine while `listen.js` does not.

Again, I can run both from a command prompt without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting I realized this was due to a folder that `listen.js` was referencing relatively.  Once I changed this to the full path everything worked fine.